# iOS 14 issue with Azure AD B2C

Tags: ios, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

We have integrated Xamarin app with AAD B2C for signup/signin/profile edit and change password. All was good with browser view enabled in iOS.

But with the recent release of iOS 14, we are facing a major roadblock for profile edit and any other B2C transactions that are happening from a B2C logged in session. We are getting a login page each time we want to edit our profile or change the password. Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Customer might move away from AAD B2C if this issue is not resolved. Please let me know if anyone else is also facing this issue.

Comment: I believe nobody is facing this issue on iOS 14.

Comment: We found that it does this on emulator but not on the real device - please confirm,

Comment: @JasSuri we are getting this issue in the real device.

Comment: Are you using the default ASWebAuthenticationWebView?

Comment: Yes, we are using the default. Not customized anything.

Comment: Consider opening a support ticket for better help : https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview.