# iOS MSAL.framework kept prompting for credentials with Azure AD B2C Edit Profile flow

Tags: swift, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I was following the [active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal) sample code. All was fine but when invoking edit profile flow, I was asked to enter credentials again. It was like B2C couldn't recognize that I was already authenticated and prompted me every time I went to the edit profile user flow. In comparison, this [ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa) Javascript SPA works. So I don't think it's my B2C configuration.

This happened to both simulator and real device with iOS 14.x. (I didn't try previous version of iOS.) Has anyone encountered the same issue? I doubt this is the intended behavior of the sample code. Anyone aware of a solution? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139793/ios-14-issue-with-azure-ad-b2c?r=SearchResults&s=1|185.5256) was reported before. Not sure if it's resolved.

Comment: Hi @Eddy Chu, did you solve this issue? I have the same problem and i can't solve it!

Answer (score 0):

As part of the call to edit profile, pass in a `loginHint` parameter with value set to the users identifier (usually their email). I believe otherwise, in the absence of `loginHint`, MSAL iOS will pass in `prompt=login` and causes the cookies to get cleared, forcing the user to login again. The object that contains loginHint is `MSALInteractiveTokenParameters`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried passing the loginHint (using email) but all it did was to prefill the email field of the login screen, and I still had to put in the password to get authenticated again before I can edit the profile.  What else is missing?

Comment: The thing was - I didn't get the callback after initial sign in.  Was I supposed to get the callback when signing in so the call to handleMSALResponse took place?